# No output from JFrame?

Tags: java, arrays, jframe

So I' trying to create a tictactoe board, however it isn't showing up with anything. 
(There is a main class but it just creates a "GameBoard" )

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

So I added the components can't believe I forgot that, I must be tired.

However now all I get is one red square.

```
    public GameBoard() 
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 195, 215);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension (300, 400));
        int count = 1;
        Rectangle board[][] = new Rectangle[3][3];


        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
                if (count == 2){

                board[row][col] = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1);
               board[row][col].setBackground(Color.RED);
               frame.add(board[row][col]);
               count--;
            } else {board[row][col] = new Rectangle(1,1,1,1);
                    board[row][col].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    frame.add(board[row][col]);
                    count++;
                }
            }}
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Rectangle Class:

```
public class Rectangle extends JComponent  {


    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h)  {
        super();
        setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
        paintChildren(g);
   }
```

}

Comment: There is no setBackground() method in Rectangle.  Is Rectangle your own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, you are missing the step to actually add the boards onto your JFrame:

```
frame.add(...);
```

in your for-loop, so you are creating the JFrame and the Rectangles, but never adding the rectangles to your JFrame.

As @AmitD pointed out, JFrame.add() doesn't accept Rectangles, so you'll need to write a class that extends JComponent to paint the Rectangles inside its `paintComponent()` method.

To address the display problem (only seeing red):

You'll need to set a Layout Manager for your `JFrame`; I think `GridLayout` would be most appropriate in your case:

```
...
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
...
```

Comment: Editted with class and another issue with the program.

Comment: @user1719605 see updated answer: You'll need to set a layout for your JFrame.

Comment: @user1719605 glad to be of help =)

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty JFrame, and create a bunch of rectangles that you store into an array, but which you never paint anywhere, so the frame stays empty.

You need to paint those rectangles on a JComponent (by overriding its `paintComponent()` method), and add this JComponent to the frame.

EDIT: as @whiskeyspider notes, there is no setBackground() method in the standard Rectangle class. So if Rectangle is a class of yours, and is a subclass of JComponent, you need to add the instances of Rectangle to the frame.

Comment: Editted with class and another issue with the program.

Comment: The method to override is `paintComponent()`. Not `paint()`. And you need to make your Rectangle return its preferred size, and to use a layout manager (a GridLayout comes to mind) in order to layout the frame. As it is, it uses a BorderLayout and everything goes at the center of the frame.